# Below is the javaScript for login validation. but output always "Incorrect username or password" i.e else condition

Tags: javascript, login-page

```js
var objLogin = [{
    fname: "sastry",
    book: "sastry"
}, {
    fname: "laxman",
    book: "laxman"
}, {
    fname: "visali",
    book: "visali"
}]
function storeData() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("fname").Value;
  var userPasswd = document.getElementById("book").Value;

  for (i = 0; i < objLogin.length; i++) {
    if (userName == objLogin[i].fname && userPasswd == objLogin[i].book) {
      console.log(userName + "Is logged in!!");
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("Incorrect username or password");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May you also include a problem statement, a [mcve], and your expected outcome? Please read [ask].

Comment: It is `.value` not `.Value` (with a lowercase `v`)

Comment: Ideally remove the else condition and put the log "invalid credentials" just before the closing brace to the function.  Right now it will say invalid over and over until it hits the credentials pair that matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the value of an input field, you should use `value` (lower case "v").

```js
var userName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
```

Also, it's great to cache your element references, like this:

```js
const userNameInput = document.getElementById("fname");
const userPasswdInput = document.getElementById("book");

function storeData() {
    const userName = userNameInput.value;
    const userPasswd = userPasswdInput.value;

    for (i = 0; i < objLogin.length; i++) {
        if (userName === objLogin[i].fname && userPasswd === objLogin[i].book) {
            console.log(userName + "Is logged in!!");
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some typo.

```js
  var userName = document.getElementById("fname").Value;
  var userPasswd = document.getElementById("book").Value;
```

As far as I know, `document.getElementById("something").value` is right;

Oh, someone answer that, but it's my first time to use stack overflow,
how can I do?

Comment: If you feel that your answer no longer contributes, you can press the `delete` button below the answer, next to `edit`. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Oh, It's not problem with writing same answer? Right?
You mean I can remain or delete, right? Thank you.

Comment: It's not a problem generally, as different answers can contain different details and information. You can choose to leave it or delete it.